# Dump Microsoft SQL Server database to an SQL script

Tags: sql-server, sql, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dump Microsoft SQL Server database to an SQL script](https://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script)

Is there any way to export a Microsoft SQL Server database to an sql script?

I'm looking for something which behaves similarly to mysqldump, taking a database name, and producing a single script which will recreate all the tables, stored procedures, reinsert all the data etc.

I've seen http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts, but I ideally want something to recreate everything (not just the data) which works in a single step to produce the final script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a duplicate: [Dump Microsoft SQL Server database to an SQL script](https://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script)