# How to convert an sql server 2008 r2 database to just 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have my local dev box running Sql Server 2008 R2.  Sadly the hosting company I am using does not support R2 yet and I need to get my database converted to a regular 2008 database.

Should I be able to run both a 2008 r2 and a regular 2008 on the same server? I am hoping that if I can run both at the same time and then use Management studio's export wizard to move the data over to the new 2008 database.

Is it possible to use the export wizard with a sql server compact file?  If I can do that then I could move the data to a compact db and take it over to another computer with 2008 installed and import the data out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would export the data to a SQL query from SQL Management Studio, import that into the hosting provider's 2008 instance, then export that new database (via backup) and import it into your local instance. When you do that, your local instance will run the database in 2008 compatibility mode.

This answer here should help you with dumping a database to .SQL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/sql-server-2005-export-table-programatically-run-a-sql-file-to-rebuild-it/1135529#1135529

Either that or the tool referenced in this post:
[Dump Microsoft SQL Server database to an SQL script](https://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script/147639#147639)

Comment: How do you "export the data to a SQL query"?

Comment: See my edits/links above :) - when using the Generate Scripts method, note that there is a "Script for Database Version", make sure to select SQL Server 2008 in that.

Comment: How'd you go @Mr Bell?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, yes, you can run different versions of SQL Server on the same machine, it only has to be different instances.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it though... SQL loves to eat RAM and disk IO (unless you limit its memory footprint in the configuration) and would make for a slow machine since you're using it for development